# I am unable to download programs from the Ubuntu Software Center with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation

I just got a new computer and I installed Ubuntu 12.04.  With Ubuntu 11.10, I had a really awesome periodic table program that I got from the Ubuntu Software Center. When I tried to download it on 12.04 from the software center, it would not download.

It's called **Periodic table of elements** and the description is *A Mendeleiev table of the chemical elements*.

Comment: It's called 'Periodic table of elements' and the description is 'A Mendeleiev table of the chemical elements'

Answer (score 1):

Which program are you talking about?  I have both installed in 12.04 and have no issues..

[image]

How are you doing it?  Is it giving you any errors?

Try this way:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gcu-bin
```

And see if it works.

Try this,  Go into Update Manager, and click on the **Settings** Button

[image]

Then click on the Ubuntu Software Tab  and go to Download from, and choose other as shown

[image]

and then choose Select Best Server.

[image]

Once its done try installing the program again.

Comment: It's the third one down.  It said to check my internet connection, however my internet connection is fine.

Comment: I ran that command and at the very end it says, "100% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]"

Answer (score 1):

1. First confirm that you are able to browse other websites.
2. Then, run these commands:

   ```
   sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists{,bakjune4}
   sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/partial{,bakjune4}
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. If above commands run successfully fine you can remove the above `bakjune4` directories safely. Otherwise change the download server using Update Manager. Follow this: Update Manager -> Settings -> Ubuntu Software (first tab) -> Change the server in Download from box. Run check for updates and install updates if any.

**Note:**
In any case you can revert to your current situation by using following commands:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/list{bakjune4,}
sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/partial{bakjune4,}
```

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Thanks for formatting the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just getting the package name from below the title and then using apt-get.

Comment: This answer would be even more useful it you were to explain how to install software with `apt-get` (to someone who has never used it and doesn't necessarily know what a terminal is).

Answer (score 0):

The package name can be found below the description of the application (first part of the version and above the size). For the 3rd one in that list "Periodic table of the elements" it is gcu-bin.

Open terminal: ctrl-t

To see all options and info about apt-get type

`apt-get --help` - you can use that argument on many command for info.

To install gcu-bin type (you need root access so proceed with sudo):

```
sudo apt-get install gcu-bin
```

press y+enter when asked something